# Spring Oauth server with custom login page

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to create Oauth server with spring security and I am new to both of them.

The flow is, when I browse the following URL

```
http://localhost:8080/OAuthServer/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/client/handler&client_id=test
```

Problem 1 :I am being redirected to login 
http://localhost:8080/OAuthServer/login
but after login authenticates my user is redirected to welcome page http://localhost:8080/OAuthServer/ instead of authorization page

Problem 2(strange): After I logout from welcome page and again do the same process again: broswe on OAuthServer/oauth/authorize?, it shows login page and after login,it is getting redirected to authorization page as expected. But this did not work on first try.

Problem 3 : Now, every time I browse OAuthServer/oauth/authorize?  it shows authorization page instead of showing login page. This time I want to authenticate some other user but goes directly to authorization page.

In all the case, there is no error and I am getting authorization code and from code, I am getting access code and refresh code and able to access my resource \employee\list using access code

I am sure some config is wrong here. Please help me out.

Security.xml

```
<!-- Entry Url -->
<sec:http pattern="/oauth/token**" create-session="stateless"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http> 

<sec:http pattern="/oauth/authorize**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="LoginEntry">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/authorize"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />   
</sec:http>

<bean id="LoginEntry"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/login" />
</bean>

<sec:http pattern="/employee/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"  >
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/employee/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<sec:http pattern="/oauth/me**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/me" method="GET"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
        before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<sec:http authentication-manager-ref="loginAuthentication"
    disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <sec:csrf />
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager id="loginAuthentication">
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <sec:user name="test" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>


<!-- Server -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    authorization-request-manager-ref="SECAuthorizationRequestManager"
    user-approval-handler-ref="SECTokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code
        authorization-code-services-ref="JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices" />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
</oauth:authorization-server>


<!-- Resource -->
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="springsec" />

</bean>
<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="com.server.security.SECClientCredentialToken">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="clientDetails" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="com.server.security.SECUserCredential">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="loginAuthentication" />
</bean>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientDetails" class="com.server.security.SECClientDetailsService">
    <property name="id" value="test" />
    <property name="secretKey" value="mycompanykey" />
</bean>

<bean id="SECTokenServicesUserApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />

</bean>

<bean id="SECAuthorizationRequestManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.DefaultAuthorizationRequestManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://serverhost:7306/Oauth?useSSL=false" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
<!-- End Persistence Layer -->

<!-- ModelViewController -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.server.security,com.server.resource,com.server.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">

    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**
I think it is because of create-session="never" on "/oauth/authorize**", please check if the jsession create for first time or not and re-check for 2nd time.

**Problem 2:**
because you already redirected to home page so session created so it can store redirect in it

**problem 3:**
you have to use another session by using incognito window, or logout and login again with different user